# cannot get multiple loops using tax_query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, wp-query

I am trying to get three loops to display. they all belong to the same post type and the same taxonomy family. but i'm trying to separate the taxonomy by three different values.

```
$argsOwners = array( 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'position',  'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'senior-management'    )));
$the_query_owners = new WP_Query( $argsOwners );
```

then i

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

then i

```
$argsSales = array( 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'position',  'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'sales' )));
$the_query_sales = new WP_Query( $argsSales );
```

and i repeat again for the third term of "admin". the problem is only the first query will work. any ideas?

EDIT EDIT EDIT

I think i figure what the issue is. It had to do with whether is was logged in or not. if i was logged in then i would only see the for query displayed. but if im logged out then i get all 3 perfectly.

Comment: Try adding `wp_reset_query()` after each query instead of `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: i tried that as well. it didn't work.

Comment: What else is going on in the theme file that could 'upset' things? And do you have any plugins activated, and if so, which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TheDeadMedic said, you've to work like that. in the default loop like:

```
while( have_posts() ) : the_post

endwhile;
```

in this case, the loop is running with the default `$wp_query` variable. But as you are running custom queries, you need to use `while( $query_obj->have_posts() ) : $query_obj->the_post();` like that

But while logged in and logged out, you shouldn't get different results :S

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `$obj->the_post()`, as opposed to just `the_post()`? For example;

```
/* Senior Management */
$query_args = array( 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'position',  'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'senior-management' ) ) );
$query_obj = new WP_Query( $query_args );

while( $query_obj->have_posts() ) : $query_obj->the_post();

    // do senior-management stuff here

endwhile;


/* Sales */
$query_args['tax_query'][0]['terms'] = 'sales';
$query_obj->query( $query_args );

while( $query_obj->have_posts() ) : $query_obj->the_post();

    // do sales stuff here

endwhile;


/* Marketing */
$query_args['tax_query'][0]['terms'] = 'marketing';
$query_obj->query( $query_args );

while( $query_obj->have_posts() ) : $query_obj->the_post();

    // do marketing stuff here

endwhile;
```

If you're doing the same 'stuff' for each loop, you could cut down your code even more by running it in a `foreach` over an array of position terms.

Comment: Ok, yes I do like that much better. I will probably change it to that.

Comment: Please look at me edit. If i'm right and it does have something to do with being logged in can someone please explain to me WHY WHY WHY would that matter???